# How to break words at paragraph width?

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

I have a few long nonsensical words I'd like to break at the same place as the other words. How do I do it?

Example below.

[image]

The text quoted is:

> As an example of the two first properties, the percentage of reads with U in the first position, or A in the tenth, consider the cluster: UUGUUUUUGGUGUUUGUAUCUACAGAA, AACAAAACAAAAAGTTGGGTAGTTTGAGAAC and AACAAAAGGACTAGTGTTCTAGAAGA
>   This cluster consists of three reads, and one of them starts with U. Hence the percentage

Ps. I'm using classicthesis if that matters.

Comment: what about an minimal working example?

Comment: They were too involved for such a small task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can use the `\hyphenation{<words>}` command to tell LaTeX how to break your very long words. I suggest to split your words every two letters like this `\hyphenation{UU-GU-UU-UU-GG-UG-UU-UG-UA-UC-UA-CA-GA-A}`.

But if you have many of these words and all different from each other I don't think this method is very clean and good.. maybe there is something better you can do but I don't know

Comment: I only had a few, that is why I was looking for a solution like this.

Answer (score 11):

Package [`seqsplit`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/seqsplit) is your friend:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{seqsplit}
\begin{document}
As an example of the two first properties, the percentage of reads
with U in the first position, or A in the tenth, consider the cluster:
\seqsplit{UUGUUUUUGGUGUUUGUAUCUACAGAA},
\seqsplit{AACAAAACAAAAAGTTGGGTAGTTTGAGAAC} and
\seqsplit{AACAAAAGGACTAGTGTTCTAGAAGA}.
This cluster consists of three reads, and one of
them starts with U. Hence the percentage \ldots
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

If you want to have hyphens, then `\seqinsert` can be redefined (see the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/seqsplit/seqsplit.pdf) of `seqsplit`):

```
\renewcommand*{\seqinsert}{\ifmmode\allowbreak\else\-\fi}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 4):

TeX has no idea how to hyphenate your long words. The discretionary hyphen command `\-` will tell TeX where a good place to hyphenate the word is.